# Writing a script that identifies polygons within a certain distance

Tags: qgis, buffer, mapinfo

To start with I have no scripting, coding or programming knowledge.

I have access to Mapinfo and QGIS. The work space will contain point and polygon data for many different things such as Tree Preservation Orders (Points), Charging Zones (Polygons), etc.

The user wants to know if a point they manually enter is within set distances of the aforementioned points and polygons e.g. Is Co-ordinate within 500m of a Tree Preservation Order (and print results); is Co-ordinate within a Charging Zone (and print results).

Is this something I can achieve in QGIS Process Modeler, or MapBasic? Overall there will be about 10 layers to query, and the user queries many co-ordinates (addresses/buildings) a day.

Comment: You could set up a point layer with virtual fields that evaluate to 0 for false, 1 for true. Calculations for the virtual fields would be something like `500 < distance($geometry, geomnearest("tree preservation order layer",$geometry))`